# Static property for type in Swift

Tags: ios, oop, swift

I want to declare static property unknown on type GpsLocation

```
class GpsLocation: NSObject {
  var lat: NSDecimalNumber = 0
  var lng: NSDecimalNumber = 0
  class var unknown:GpsLocation = GpsLocation(lat: 0, lng: 0)

  init(lat:NSDecimalNumber, lng: NSDecimalNumber){
       self.lat = lat
       self.lng = lng
  }
```

}

I get "Class variables not yet supported"

How can I declare a static property in Swift?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why not use a `CLLocation` object?

Comment: just define it above viewDidLoad

Comment: @Antonio, thanks, your comment was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're really trying to do, but from the naming, you'd probably be better off actually using an optional GpsLocation to indicate an unknown position rather than comparing it to an illegal value (which is actually, in this case, a very legitimate GPS location)

This is really the intended usage of optionals, to indicate that something has an invalid or unknown value, without trying to come up with some otherwise invalid value to stuff them with.

In any case, what you're actually trying to done can be done by actually implementing the getter in the method:

```
class var unknown:GPSLocation { return GPSLocation(lat: 0, lng: 0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class GpsLocation: NSObject {
      var lat: NSDecimalNumber = 0
      var lng: NSDecimalNumber = 0
      class var unknown:GpsLocation = GpsLocation(lat: 0, lng: 0)

  struct Static {
    static var unkwown:GpsLocation = GpsLocation(lat: 0, lng: 0)
  }

  init(lat:NSDecimalNumber, lng: NSDecimalNumber){
       self.lat = lat
       self.lng = lng
  }

}
```